# How to mask on certain condition in python

Tags: python

I am trying to mask list of tuples whenever QAZ comes the word associated with QAZ should be masked with (X)

```
  x = [('MANU', 'QAZ'),('SHIVAM', 'QAZ'),(',', ','),('RAVI', 'QAZ'),('BAKER', 'QAZ')]

 def search_tuple(tups, elem):
    return filter(lambda tup: elem in tup, tups)
 print(search_tuple(x, 'QAZ'))
```

Till the i a able to print but it only return

```
        filter object at 0x00000242E06CA2E8
```

At the end i just want to mask like MANU, RAVI, SHIVAM should be masked which i am not able to perform

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: how can i mask it if contain QAZ?

Comment: Apparently we don't understand what you mean by "mask". That's why you should post your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

The `filter` function returns an iterator.

An iterator is a set of instruction on how to produce a container, but it is not a container.

For example,

```
L = ["happy"]*10000
f = map(lambda x: x + " dayz", L)
print(f)
```

The output is `<map object at 0x016BE520>`.
In my example, `f` does ***NOT*** have 10000 elements. 
`f` occupies a teeny-tiny piece of memory -- very small.
If you want a container, you have to create one.

For example, you can use `list` and write:

```
list(filter(lambda tup: elem in tup, tups))
```

or

```
f      = map(lambda x: x + " dayz", L)
f_list = list(f)
```

Comment: how can i mask it if contain QAZ?